# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'client_socket' and 'statusMessage'

Tags: python

```
import socket
import sys

class SimpleClient:
    def __init__(self, client_socket, statusMessage):
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        self.statusMessage = statusMessage

    def connectToServer(self):
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        host  = 'cs5700sp15.ccs.neu.edu'
        port  = 27993

        remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

        try:
            self.client_socket.connect((remote_ip, port))
        except socket.error:
            print ('Connection failed')
            sys.exit()

        print ('Connection successful')

    def sendHelloMessage(self):
        """This funtion sends the initial HELLO message to the server"""
        nu_id = input('Enter your NUID: ')
        hello_message = 'cs5700spring2015 HELLO {}\n'.format(nu_id)
        self.client_socket.send(bytes(hello_message, 'ascii'))

    def receiveStatusMessage(self):
        """This function receives the STATUS message from the server"""
        self.statusMessage = str(self.client_socket.recv(1024))
        print (self.statusMessage)

        #handleStatusMessage()

def main():
  client = SimpleClient()
  client.connectToServer()
  client.sendHelloMessage()
  client.receiveStatusMessage()  

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sanketdeshpande/Documents/workspace/test/project01-simpleclient.py", line 49, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
  File "/Users/sanketdeshpande/Documents/workspace/test/project01-simpleclient.py", line 44, in main
    client = SimpleClient()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'client_socket' and 'statusMessage'
```

Comment: It take two parameters (client_socket, statusMessage) and you give it nothing.

Comment: ...further your problem has nothing to do with sockets but with basic Python use. You should reduce your problems to a minimal example before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class SimpleClient:
    def __init__(self, client_socket, statusMessage):
```

Your class taking two arguments, but when you call it;

```
client = SimpleClient()
```

You didn't write any arguments. So you have to put 2 arguments they may be `None`.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to allow passing no arguments to the Class initiator, you have to define the initiator with default values set to `None` (or whatever is appropriate).

For example,

```
def __init__(self, client_socket=None, statusMessage=""):
    self.client_socket = client_socket
    self.statusMessage = statusMessage
```

Now you can call your class instantiation without passing initialization parameters.

```
client = SimpleClient()
```