# Python 3.5 'master' and 'widgetName' in "__init__"

Tags: python

I'm calling another python file from the current file, and using a function that calls all functions in the other file.

```
def choose1():
    def openthis():
        import board1
        for i in dir(board1):
            item = getattr(board1,i)
            if callable(item):
                item()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        openthis()
```

Note: `board1` is a python file.

With this function, I get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'master' and 'widgetName'
```

I have looked around, and saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122963/typeerror-init-missing-2-required-positional-arguments-client-socket-a), but it did not mention `master` and `widgetName`, and I'm unsure of what they mean and what I should do.

Comment: "using a function that calls all functions in the other file" - first, that's a terrible idea. Second, classes are callable.

Comment: The code you posted isn't enough for us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if callable(item):
    item()
```

`item` is a class, and you're attempting to create an instance of that class, but that class has two required arguments, and you're not passing any arguments at all.

Comment: A class? What makes it into a class?

Comment: You're iterating over all the things in the `board1` module.  One of those things happens to be a class, and classes are callable.

Comment: There are no classes in `board1`

Comment: Given the error you're getting, that seems unlikely.  Edit the question to include the contents of `board1`.

Comment: When a module imports something, the imported name becomes an attribute of that module.  `board1` import lots of things from `tkinter` and `random`.  You're trying to call them all.

Comment: You've dumped every class or function from `tkinter` and `random` into your module. There are a lot of classes there.

Comment: So should I import them in the current file, and then call board1?

Comment: No, because this is a terrible way to solve whatever actual problem you have.  What are you _really_ trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your file imports all of tkinter and random directly into its own namespace. So, when you iterate over everything in that namespace, you get the objects from those modules too.

One fix would be to not use `from ... import *`, but import the modules themselves - `import tkinter`. But really the full fix is not to do what you're doing at all.